# Where does linux store the logs for Ifdown / ifup?

Tags: logs, network-interface

When I execute `ifdown` / `ifup` on a network card and show where are the events logged?

Comment: Do they really have logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're stored in `/var/log/messages`.

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you have `systemd` as init process, you can run

```bsh
sudo journalctl -kb --pager-end
```

and find messages

Comment: Depending on the system and what groups the current user is a member of (`adm`, `systemd-journal` or `wheel`),  `sudo` may not be needed.

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan thanks for notice